# Hibernate mapping a map without a join table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use hibernate to map an object like this:

```
@Entity
public class ParentClass {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int Id;

    @OneToMany
    Map<String, ChildClass> map;
}

@Entity
public class ChildClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int Id;

    String text;
}
```

I don't want Hibernate to create a join table.  I want it to add a column to the table for ChildClass.  I'd also prefer not to add a field for the key in ChildClass.  Ideally, when saving the object Hibernate would automatically take the key in the map and save it in the corresponding table, and do the reverse when querying.  Is this possible?

If I do have to add a field to ChildClass for the key, can hibernate populate this field automatically with the key from the map?  The reason I ask is because I'm getting my data from a JSON web service and using Jackson to parse it and I don't know of a way to make Jackson copy the keys to the fields in the value objects.  I could write code to do that manually, but I`d rather avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Unidirectional relation without jointable:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID")
    public Set<Ticket> getTickets() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Ticket implements Serializable {
    ... //no bidir
}
```

Bidirectional without jointable:

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

It's from documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/ 
Apply these samples to your case.